# Combobox List passing string

Tags: combobox, vb6, styles

I have a VB6 application that has been running for quite sometime. Currently I'm trying to update one of the form that has a combobox 2.0. Because the combobox is populated with hundreds of items - I'm trying to update it so that users are able to click on a look up button next to it, where another window opens up with all the items from the combobox. User will be able to search by keyword and/or select an item and double click on it and have it appear in the combobox. The issue I'm having is with trying to pass no value or "" when CANCEL is clicked. I'm able to pass the value if I in the properties window my STYLE Is set to COMBO rather than list. However, the issue I come across is that with COMBO the value (text) in the combobox sometimes is not aligned properly. Is there a way to pass a "" value to a combobox 2.0 without changing the style to COMBO?

Comment: If they hit cancel try setting the ListIndex of your combo to -1 rather than setting the text property.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder this actually worked. post as answer and i'll accept Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they hit cancel set the `ListIndex` of your combo to -1 rather than setting the text property.  This is the value for no item being selected.